# Why are my domain assembly's log messages being dropped while the websites logs are being written

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

I'm using log4net to implement logging in an asp.net mvc4 web application.  Log messages originating in my website project get written to the log just fine but log messages originating from the assembly dll disappear. what would cause this?

Comment: Whats a handler in log4net parlance?  I'm a bit of a cargo-cult programmer when it comes to log4net; I put the lines in the places and magically my stuff is logged.

Comment: This appears to have been an assembly version issue.  I rebuilt the project file's references to the log4net assembly and it works now.